# How to POST JSON from browser to a different domain?

Tags: javascript, json, http, post, http-post

From a webpage, I need to send JSON data using POST method to a different domain.

I can use a form with hidden fields, but then POST data is application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of application/json, and is "name=value" instead of "value"

I can use XMLHttpRequest (directly or through any API) to send arbitrary JSON data in the POST payload, but then I run into cross-domain limitation.

Also, I need the browser to really navigate to the new url, because what we are really doing is to invoke a different application sending some parameters.

Any options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are limited to the browser, then no - there are no other options.  Browsers cannot perform cross-domain `POST` requests to arbitrary domains.  This is a security feature.

If you have full control over the server (or if it's already configured for this), you might consider [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), but this feature is not strongly supported yet.